# Is there a %*SUB-MAIN-OPTS pair for short option processing?

Tags: command-line-arguments, raku

The `multi sub MAIN()` command line parsing in Perl6 is sweet!

As far as I can tell from the [Command Line Interface](https://docs.raku.org/language/create-cli#Parsing_the_command_line_parameters_into_a_capture) docs there is only one option supported in the dynamic hash %*SUB-MAIN-OPTS  to manipulate the option processing (that being `:named-anywhere`).

Perhaps I've missed the obvious, but is there an existing/supported option to take 'old fashioned' single dash options?

For example:

```
#Instead of this...
myprogram.raku --alpha=value1 --beta==value2 --chi

#... short options like this
myprogram.raku -a value1 -bvalue2 -c
```

Or is this best processed manually or with an external module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can sort of emulate this as-is, although you still have to an = ala `-a=foo`, and still technically have `--a=foo` in addition to `--alpha` and `-a`

```
sub MAIN(:a(:$alpha)!) {
    say $alpha;
}
```

...so you probably want to use https://github.com/Leont/getopt-long6

```
use Getopt::Long;
get-options("alpha=a" => my $alpha);
```

Comment: I didn't realise I could use a single '-' instead of double. Your alias solution makes for much less typing on the command line